# AttributeError: 'OpDefLibrary' object has no attribute '_apply_op_helper'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

Error While I run it was :

> File
>   "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 327, in apply_op
>       output_structure, is_stateful, op = self._apply_op_helper(
>
> AttributeError: 'OpDefLibrary' object has no attribute
>   '_apply_op_helper'

Looking for someone can help me with this error.

Thanks !

Comment: What tensorflow version do you use?

Comment: tensorflow version 1.10.0

Comment: Does this problem happen when you import tensorflow?

Comment: I don't have this problem with TF 1.10.0 on windows 10.

Comment: You could try reinstalling your tensorflow.

Comment: importing tensorflow doesnt show any error ! But while running the script it does

Comment: Then please paste the full script.